# Extracting multiple words from between periods in R

Tags: r

I have a bunch of cell data that I'm trying to properly parse and transfer over to an existing workflow, but I need to find the number of cells positive for different markers in a given region. The way that the program I'm using exports cell data is basically as the number of cells positive for certain markers, disregarding everything else.

What I want to do is extract all of the cell markers between the periods and have a list of markers present in the dataset, so the data below would produce a list containing "COL1A1", "DDR1", "PanCK", and "CD8". Obviously I could just write a list containing all of those, but I want it to be reusable for future datasets that might have different markers.

```
 [1] "Num.Detections"                   "Num.CD8."                        
 [3] "Num.COL1A1."                      "Num.COL1A1...CD8."               
 [5] "Num.COL1A1...DDR1."               "Num.COL1A1...DDR1...CD8."        
 [7] "Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK."       "Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK...CD8."
 [9] "Num.COL1A1...PanCK."              "Num.COL1A1...PanCK...CD8."       
[11] "Num.DDR1."                        "Num.DDR1...CD8."                 
[13] "Num.DDR1...PanCK."                "Num.DDR1...PanCK...CD8."         
[15] "Num.PanCK."                       "Num.PanCK...CD8."                
[17] "Num.PanCK...COL1A1."              "Num.PanCK...COL1A1...CD8."       
[19] "Num.PanCK...COL1A1...DDR1."       "Num.PanCK...COL1A1...DDR1...CD8."
[21] "Num.PanCK...DDR1."                "Num.PanCK...DDR1...CD8."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here´s a base approach

```
output <- unique(unlist(strsplit(sub("Num\\.", "", string), "\\.", )))
output[!output %in% c("Detections", "")]
[1] "CD8"    "COL1A1" "DDR1"   "PanCK"
```

Another option:

```
unique(sub(".*\\.(\\w+)\\.", "\\1", string))[-1]
[1] "CD8"    "COL1A1" "DDR1"   "PanCK"
```

data:

```
c("Num.Detections", "Num.CD8.", "Num.COL1A1.", "Num.COL1A1...CD8.", 
"Num.COL1A1...DDR1.", "Num.COL1A1...DDR1...CD8.", "Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK.", 
"Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK...CD8.", "Num.COL1A1...PanCK.", "Num.COL1A1...PanCK...CD8.", 
"Num.DDR1.", "Num.DDR1...CD8.", "Num.DDR1...PanCK.", "Num.DDR1...PanCK...CD8.", 
"Num.PanCK.", "Num.PanCK...CD8.", "Num.PanCK...COL1A1.", "Num.PanCK...COL1A1...CD8.", 
"Num.PanCK...COL1A1...DDR1.", "Num.PanCK...COL1A1...DDR1...CD8.", 
"Num.PanCK...DDR1.", "Num.PanCK...DDR1...CD8.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split by `"..."`, then remove extraneous characters:

```r
vec[-1] |>   # assuming the first element "Num.Detections" should be omitted
  strsplit("\\.{3}") |>
  unlist() |>
  gsub("Num|\\.", "", x = _) |>
  unique()
# "CD8"    "COL1A1" "DDR1"   "PanCK"
```

Or to get counts, replace `unique()` with `table()`:

```r
vec[-1] |>
  strsplit("\\.{3}") |>
  unlist() |>
  gsub("Num|\\.", "", x = _) |>
  table()
#   CD8 COL1A1   DDR1  PanCK 
#    11     12     12     14
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)

unique(na.omit(str_extract(vec, "\\.(\\w+)\\.", group=1)))
[1] "COL1A1" "DDR1"   "PanCK"  "CD8"
```

##### Data

```
vec <- c("Num.Detections", "Num.COL1A1.", 
"Num.COL1A1...DDR1.", "Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK.", 
"Num.COL1A1...PanCK.", "Num.DDR1.", "Num.DDR1...PanCK.", "Num.PanCK.", 
"Num.PanCK...COL1A1.", "Num.PanCK...COL1A1...DDR1.", "Num.PanCK...DDR1.", 
"Num.CD8.", "Num.COL1A1...CD8.", "Num.COL1A1...DDR1...CD8.", 
"Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK...CD8.", "Num.COL1A1...PanCK...CD8.", 
"Num.DDR1...CD8.", "Num.DDR1...PanCK...CD8.", "Num.PanCK...CD8.", 
"Num.PanCK...COL1A1...CD8.", "Num.PanCK...COL1A1...DDR1...CD8.", 
"Num.PanCK...DDR1...CD8.")
```